# Looping a sequence of withAnimation functions

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm creating a loading animation in SwiftUI (since Lottie is not supported for WatchOS and I can't get SDWebImageLottieCoder to work together with SwiftUI). This animation consists of a function called animateSpinner which goes over a bunch of withAnimation functions together with Dispatchqueue to mimic keyframes (delay was not working either).

Now this allows me to play the animation once, but how can I change the function to play forever ?

I tried looking into putting it inside a timer, or to use "while true" but all were unsuccessful.

Any ideas ?

[image]

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var intro = false
    @State private var mainIn = false
    @State private var mainOut = false
    @State private var outro = false
    
    @State private var hideIntro: Bool = false
    @State private var hideMainIn = true
    @State private var hideMainOut = true
    @State private var hideOutro = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // 01. Light Circle from background to right side
            CirclesAnimated(lightCircleScaleFrom: 0.1, lightCircleScaleTo: 0.125, darkCircleScaleFrom: 0.15, darkCircleScaleTo: 0.125, lightCirclePositionFrom: 0, lightCirclePositionTo: 25, darkCirclePositionFrom: 0, darkCirclePositionTo: -25, lightCircleDarknessFrom: -0.5, lightCircleDarknessTo: -0.25,darkCircleDarknessFrom: 0, darkCircleDarknessTo: -0.25, frontCircle: .dark, animate: $intro)
                .opacity(hideIntro ? 0 : 1)
            // 02. Light Circle from right side to foreground.
            CirclesAnimated(lightCircleScaleFrom: 0.125, lightCircleScaleTo: 0.15, darkCircleScaleFrom: 0.125, darkCircleScaleTo: 0.1, lightCirclePositionFrom: 25, lightCirclePositionTo: 0, darkCirclePositionFrom: -25, darkCirclePositionTo: 0, lightCircleDarknessFrom: -0.25, lightCircleDarknessTo: 0, darkCircleDarknessFrom: -0.25, darkCircleDarknessTo: -0.5, frontCircle: .light, animate: $mainIn)
                .opacity(hideMainIn ? 0 : 1)
            // 03. Light Circle from foreground to left side
            CirclesAnimated(lightCircleScaleFrom: 0.15, lightCircleScaleTo: 0.125, darkCircleScaleFrom: 0.1, darkCircleScaleTo: 0.125, lightCirclePositionFrom: 0, lightCirclePositionTo: -25, darkCirclePositionFrom: 0, darkCirclePositionTo: 25, lightCircleDarknessFrom: 0, lightCircleDarknessTo: -0.25, darkCircleDarknessFrom: -0.5, darkCircleDarknessTo: -0.25, frontCircle: .light, animate: $mainOut)
                .opacity(hideMainOut ? 0 : 1)
            // 04. Light Circle from left side to background
            CirclesAnimated(lightCircleScaleFrom: 0.125, lightCircleScaleTo: 0.1, darkCircleScaleFrom: 0.125, darkCircleScaleTo: 0.15, lightCirclePositionFrom: -25, lightCirclePositionTo: 0, darkCirclePositionFrom: 25, darkCirclePositionTo: 0, lightCircleDarknessFrom: -0.25, lightCircleDarknessTo: -0.5, darkCircleDarknessFrom: -0.25, darkCircleDarknessTo: 0, frontCircle: .dark, animate: $outro)
                .opacity(hideOutro ? 0 : 1)
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            animateSpinner()
        }
    }
    
    private func animateSpinner() {
        
        withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
            intro.toggle()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.hideIntro = true
            self.hideMainIn = false
            withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                mainIn.toggle()
                
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.hideMainIn = true
            self.hideMainOut = false
            withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                mainOut.toggle()
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.hideMainOut = true
            self.hideOutro = false
            withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                outro.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}


enum FrontCircle {
    case light
    case dark
}

struct CirclesAnimated: View {
    
    var lightCircleScaleFrom: CGFloat
    var lightCircleScaleTo: CGFloat
    var darkCircleScaleFrom: CGFloat
    var darkCircleScaleTo: CGFloat
    
    var lightCirclePositionFrom: CGFloat
    var lightCirclePositionTo: CGFloat
    var darkCirclePositionFrom: CGFloat
    var darkCirclePositionTo: CGFloat
    
    var lightCircleDarknessFrom: Double
    var lightCircleDarknessTo: Double
    var darkCircleDarknessFrom: Double
    var darkCircleDarknessTo: Double
    
    var frontCircle: FrontCircle
    
    
    @EnvironmentObject var theme: ThemeSelectionService
    
    @Binding var animate: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        if frontCircle == .dark {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .scale(animate ? lightCircleScaleTo : lightCircleScaleFrom)
                    .foregroundColor(theme.lightColor)
                    .offset(x: animate ? lightCirclePositionTo : lightCirclePositionFrom)
                    .brightness(animate ? lightCircleDarknessTo : lightCircleDarknessFrom)
                Circle()
                    .scale(animate ? darkCircleScaleTo : darkCircleScaleFrom)
                    .foregroundColor(theme.darkColor)
                    .offset(x: animate ? darkCirclePositionTo : darkCirclePositionFrom)
                    .brightness(animate ? darkCircleDarknessTo : darkCircleDarknessFrom)
            }
        } else {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .scale(animate ? darkCircleScaleTo : darkCircleScaleFrom)
                    .foregroundColor(theme.darkColor)
                    .offset(x: animate ? darkCirclePositionTo : darkCirclePositionFrom)
                    .brightness(animate ? darkCircleDarknessTo : darkCircleDarknessFrom)
                Circle()
                    .scale(animate ? lightCircleScaleTo : lightCircleScaleFrom)
                    .foregroundColor(theme.lightColor)
                    .offset(x: animate ? lightCirclePositionTo : lightCirclePositionFrom)
                    .brightness(animate ? lightCircleDarknessTo : lightCircleDarknessFrom)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to do the animation. I try to avoid DispatchQueues in the middle of animations because they can be glitchy at times. I used a Timer to update a counter with circlePositions 0,1,2,3 and updated modifiers based on the circle's position. I incorporated an offset for the 2nd circle so that it's always 2 positions ahead of the first one.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var counter: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .scaleEffect(getScale(n: 0))
                .offset(x: getOffset(n: 0))
                .brightness(getBrightness(n: 0))
                .zIndex(getZIndex(n: 0))
            
            Circle()
                .scaleEffect(getScale(n: 2))
                .offset(x: getOffset(n: 2))
                .brightness(getBrightness(n: 2))
                .zIndex(getZIndex(n: 2))
        }
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
            withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                counter = getPosition(n: 1)
            }
        })
        // TO BE DELETED
        .overlay(
            Text("\(counter) : \(getPosition(n: 2))")
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .animation(nil)
            , alignment: .top
        )
            
    }
    
    func getPosition(n circleOffset: Int) -> Int {
        return (counter + circleOffset) % 4
    }
    
    func getScale(n circleOffset: Int) -> CGFloat {
        switch getPosition(n: circleOffset) {
        case 1: return 0.075
        case 3: return 0.125
        default: return 0.1
        }
    }
    
    func getOffset(n circleOffset: Int) -> CGFloat {
        switch getPosition(n: circleOffset) {
        case 0: return -25
        case 2: return 25
        default: return 0
        }
    }
    
    func getBrightness(n circleOffset: Int) -> Double {
        switch getPosition(n: circleOffset) {
        case 1: return -0.5
        case 3: return 0
        default: return -0.25
        }
    }
    
    func getZIndex(n circleOffset: Int) -> Double {
        switch getPosition(n: circleOffset) {
        case 0, 3: return 2
        default: return 1
        }
    }
    
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: niiiice, that's neat ! thanks a lot for this approach.